# How can i fix Pymeeus install "Error: command errored out with exit status 1: ..."

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

When i try install PyMeeus its give this error. I try to install nerualprophet and its download the pymeeus and gives error. I tried `pip install --user pymeeus` and  `pip3 install --user pymeeus` versions. I use python 3.7. Also i install this too

```
flake8>=3.1.0
mccabe>=0.5.1
pycodestyle>=2.1.0
pyflakes>=2.0.0
pytest>=3.0.1
pytest-cov>=2.0.0
```

They are in the requirement file in the pymeeus. How can i solve this error ?

[image: error]

Comment: In future, please don't paste images with errors, only code. If it contains text that's not in English, make sure to translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the issue is with messed up name for the temporary directory, `[WinError 267]` is The directory name is invalid - for those of us who do not speak Turkish. It tries to write to `DOUKAN~1` and fails. Check if that path is accessible.

### Solution

Set `TMPDIR` environment variable to point at place that has a proper name, no non-ASCII characters, e.g. `C:\tmp\` (create it first).

In CMD:

```
set TMPDIR=C:\tmp
pip install --build C:\tmp pymeeus
```

`--build` set directory to unpack packages into and build in.

#### Alternative

Use Anaconda instead of pypi:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pymeeus
```

In both cases I'd strongly advise to create a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I handle creating anaconda enviroment and installed the libraries.